# How to cancel text change of EditText after showing a message?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can disable `EditText`, but then the user will simply unable to change the text. The behaviour I am trying to implement is that, if the user tries to type something (or any other changing method such as pasting), showing a message like "You cannot edit this text because of something.".

At first, I thought I could show the message using `TextWatcher`, but there seems to be no way to cancel the change. How can I achieve the behaviour I am looking for? The only way I could think is the following really dirty way.

> Have a backup of the text of the EditText. When EditText is changed,
>   if `isReverting` is false, show the message and set `isReverting` to
>   true. If `isReverting` is true, just set it to false. Set the backup
>   to the EditText.

Comment: if you don't want to allow paste then try longClickable false in xml. it will not show copy paste option then

Comment: No, not just disabling editing, but showing a message if the user tries to edit the text and disallow editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work great. You can also just store the unmodifiable value in a variable and simply change the text back in [`afterTextChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) if the value is different.

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 2):

A `TextWatcher` will fullfill the need in your case . Do the validation inside `afterTextChange()`. Below is an example.

```
et_Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String input=s.toString();
            if(s.length()>4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You can only input 4 letters",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String old=input.substring(0,4);
                et_Name.setText(old);
                et_Name.setSelection(old.length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `EditText` non editable by using the following property programatically

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

no need of `textChangeListner`